# Pygame: list shown truncated in a surface

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

So, I'm trying to build an application that shows some info regarding the system using Pygame to display them graphically. One of the information I'm trying to show is a list os processes running in the system, with their pid, name and cpu usage percentage. The problem is that when I try to display it on a pygame surface, it becomes truncated, as if trying to write the whole list into a single point in the screen. When trying to use counters to spread the list across the screen, it becomes a single diagonal line. Is there any way I can display this list correctly?

(Also, considering it's a huge list, would anyone also know a way to separate it into different surfaces according to the length of the list?)

```
def processos_ativos():
    
    listOfProcessNames = []

    for proc in psutil.process_iter():

        pInfoDict = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name', 'cpu_percent'])

        listOfProcessNames.append(pInfoDict)

    for elem in listOfProcessNames:
        #print(elem)
        elem = str(elem)
        horizontal = 0
        vertical = 0

        for i in elem:
            text = font.render(i, 1, verde)
            horizontal += 1
            vertical += 1
            tela.blit(text,(10*vertical,25*horizontal))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When trying to use counters to spread the list across the screen, it becomes a single diagonal line.

The effect is caused, because you increment the vertical and horizontal position of the text in the inner loop. Increment only the horizontal position in the inner loop. The vertical position has to be incremented in then outer loop. In the inner loop you have to iterate through the dictionary:

```py
def processos_ativos():

    listOfProcessNames = [proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name', 'cpu_percent']) for proc in psutil.process_iter()]
    
    horizontal = 0
    for dictionary in listOfProcessNames:

        vertical = 0
        for key in dictionary:
            elem = dictionary[key]
            text = font.render(elem, True, verde)
            
            tela.blit(text,(10*vertical,25*horizontal))
            vertical += 1

        horizontal += 1
```